# Cannot get code to run on codepen.io

Tags: javascript, debugging

Go to codepen.io and run this code in teh picture in the JS window.  Please help me to run this sample code

[image]

Comment: share the URL of the pen

Comment: http://codepen.io/shihanrehman/pen/JGJpmV?editors=101

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I cannot get the code to show in the console of codepen.io if you type it in the js window

Answer (score 2):

check this updated [pen](http://codepen.io/gurvinder372/pen/rxwdNo?editors=101)

```
var multiply = function(a,b){
  return a + b;
}
document.body.innerHTML += multiply(3,6);
```

you need to [manipulate dom](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to see values in the codepen console.